# fluentd cannot connect to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, efk

I run the stack EFK through docker-compose, the stack starts, kibana and elasticsearch go through the initial setup. fluentd throws the following error at startup:

```
"The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product."
```

kibana 8.2.0
elasticsearch 8.2.0

Maybe fluent can't log in over https, where to look for the problem?

Dockerfile fluentd:

```
FROM fluentd:latest

# Use root account to use apk
USER root

# below RUN includes plugin as examples elasticsearch is not required
# you may customize including plugins as you wish
RUN apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .build-deps \
        sudo build-base ruby-dev \
 && sudo gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch \
 && sudo gem sources --clear-all \
 && apk del .build-deps \
 && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/lib/ruby/gems/*/cache/*.gem

COPY conf/fluent.conf /fluentd/etc/
COPY entrypoint.sh /bin/

USER fluent
```

fluentd.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host elasticsearch
  port 9200
  user fluent
  password 6M9eXThhypVjV8h
  logstash_format true
  logstash_prefix fluentd
  logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
</match>
```

the username and password for fluent are created in kibana

Comment: is kibana able to connect?

Comment: The initial configuration of kubana and elasticsearch has been carried out, I can open the ip address:5601 in the browser, and walk around the kibana web interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by downgrading the EFK version and changing the Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.12.0-debian-1.0
USER root
RUN gem uninstall -I elasticsearch && gem install elasticsearch -v 7.17.0
RUN ["gem", "install", "fluent-plugin-elasticsearch", "--no-document", "--version", "5.0.3"]
USER fluent
```

docker-compose.yml

```
## EFK Stack
  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf/fluent.conf:/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    networks:
      - efk

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    expose:
      - "9200"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - efk

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.13.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - efk

networks:
  efk:
    driver: bridge
```

fluent.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix fluentd
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name access_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```